# Accessing LXC frm host over local network

Tags: linux, linux-networking, lxc

Hay!
I searched a lot, but it seems this is not common issue.
Comments are much appreciated!

```
# Set variables
HOST=192.168.0.254
LXC=192.168.0.105
```

I am dealing with LXC (NGINX, MySQL) and I am not able to access the NGINX websites from my host over the local network (browser):

```
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

There is no ping from the $HOST to its $LXC container:

```
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2040ms
```

On the other hand the $HOST is reachable from the $LXC:

```
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2045ms
```

The host has the **lxdbr0** bridge device, through which the LXC containers connect to the local network. Not sure if the containers connect to the local network through this device tho.
Example of the network interface configuration on one LXC - **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0**:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
HOSTNAME=LXC_NAME
NM_CONTROLLED=no
TYPE=Ethernet
MTU=
DHCP_HOSTNAME=`hostname`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by reconfiguring LXD so my containers can connect to the lxdbr0 instead of directly to my host's local network (the router).

Answer (score 0):

Common pitfall when working with Virtualization: Do you use something like VirtualBox for your LXC host? Then you have to allow Promiscuous mode for the network interface of the host. Otherwise tenant traffic from the LXC container will be rejected.

Please be more specific with $HOST and $LXC. Is $HOST the IP of the LXC host or your PC with browser? Is $LXC the IP of the LXC host or the IP of the LXC container?

Comment: My host is Ubuntu 16.04 and I am not running VirtualBox, but the native LXC service. $HOST and $LXC are the IP addresses of the host and the container respectively, set at the beginning of my post. Indeed $HOST is the IP of the PC with browser, from which I would like to access the web server on the container.

Comment: What is your LXD bridge configuration? Please add it to your post: `lxc network show lxdbr0`. Do you have a virtual or physical LXC host?

Comment: The LXC host is physical machine. Seems that there is no network lxc command:
$ lxc network show lxdbr0
error: unknown command: network

My LXC version:
$ lxc --version
2.0.11

Comment: Well, that suprises me. Do you use LXD or low level LXC? Were does your `lxdbr0` bridge come from if you are not using LXD? Did you change the name? The default LXC bridge is called `lxcbr0` Please also provide your container config: `/var/lib/lxc/CONTAINER/config`

Comment: It seems I have the LXD service. I thought I had LXD, but removed it and I suppose the lxd bridge was left over.
`/var/lib/lxd/containers$ /etc/init.d/lxd status
● lxd.service - LXD - main daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lxd.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-07-17 16:12:07 EEST; 6min ago`
The /var/lib/lxc directory does not exist.

Comment: I see it. LXD `2.0.11` doesn't support the `lxc network` command, so that is the reason why this wasn't working. Are you able to update LXD? Which OS is running on your LXD host? And also add to your post which changes you have made. Per default, LXD does NAT over the `lxdbr0` bridge with a virtual private network.

Comment: My host OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
I setup LXD long time ago and I do not remember the network configuration :(
I am not able to execute lxd init, because I already have configured containers.
Not quite sure how to check how the LXC containers get connected to the local network - I suspect it is not through the bridge, but maybe directly to the router DHCP? Any tips will be much appreciated ^_^

Comment: You can view your bridge configuration via `brctl show` (`bridge-utils` package needed). I'm running dozens of updated Ubuntu 16.04 hosts here, the current version of LXD is `3.0.1`. Please update your system if possible.

Comment: Seems that bridge is not configured:
`$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id  STP enabled interfaces
lxdbr0  8000.000000000000 no `
I am not quite sure how I setup the network for LXC containers (the way they connect to the network, my host is part of), but it seems that it is not via the bridge.
LXD seems the latest version, available:
`$ sudo apt upgrade lxd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lxd is already the newest version (2.0.11-0ubuntu1~16.04.4).`

Comment: My fault. I'm using `xenial-backports`. `xenial-updates` provides version `2.0.11` only. So if you don't use any bridging, do you use the physical NIC of the LXD host for the container?

Comment: I am not quite sure, but I suspect that I do, this is possible reason for the reported issue, but I am not sure how to check it :(